# fstream .eof() loop working in Xcode but not g++

Tags: c++, xcode, g++, ifstream

Hi I have following loop for reading in persons:

```
void personFin(vector<Person>* persvect, string filename)
{
    ifstream personfile(filename);
    string name;
    int lhstrength;
    int rhstrength;
    int erasiveskill;
    int ID = 1;
    cout << "reading in persons" << endl;
    if (personfile.good())
    {
        while (!(personfile >> name).eof())
        {
            cout << "start read in " << ID << endl;
            personfile >> lhstrength;
            personfile >> rhstrength;
            personfile >> erasiveskill;
            Person temp(name, lhstrength, rhstrength, erasiveskill, ID);
            persvect->push_back(temp);
            cout << "end read in " << ID << endl;
            ID++;
        }
        personfile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Cannot open file.\n";
    }
}
```

I executed my program in Xcode and everything worked fine when I compile it with g++ the input file loop is infinite

thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried opening your file in binary mode?

Comment: I think it's better to use `while (!(personfile >> name))` (without eof()), because a read could fail for some other reason, so failbit could be on, but eofbit off.